# Python strict CSV DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to test bad CSV input data but I'm not able to simulate it.

my code is:

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(fd.readline(), delimiters=',;')
dialect.strict = True
fd.seek(0)
reader = csv.DictReader(fd, dialect=dialect)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

There is no difference if I use dialect.strict = True or dialect.strict = False on any my data files.
Can someone show me CSV data raising Error when dialect.strict = True and no exception when dialect.strict = False?

Python doc for a reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.strict

Answer (score 1):

Setting `dialect.strict = True` would make the reader raise an exception when the input data does not have a matching ending quote.

For example:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

fd = StringIO('''a,b
x,"y''')
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(fd.readline(), delimiters=',;')
dialect.strict = False
fd.seek(0)
reader = csv.DictReader(fd, dialect=dialect)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

would output:

```
{'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'}
```

But setting `dialect.strict = True` would produce:

```
_csv.Error: unexpected end of data
```